# Is it an issue if my drive is assigned to B:?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, disk-management

I have read that drives are not typically assigned to B: because it used to be assigned to floppy disks in MSDOS. IS this still an issue? I partitioned my new SSD to the B: location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably not.  The B drive was commonly a floppy disk drive for much older machines.  It would only possibly be an issue if you were running ancient software.

Comment: That's what I assumed, It is just odd because I have not seen anyone set their drives to the B: location before.

Comment: @AndrewBoote Windows still reserves A and B for floppies, even though really nothing uses them anymore.  Back in the DOS days, programs occassionally were hard coded for floppies, but even that was rare.  Reserving them is merely a safety "feature" for the oldest legacy software.